# Visual Composer Backend editor custom made element

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-c++

This is my first time making custom Wordpress Visual Composer element. So far everything works ok except one thing:

When added to backend editor element doesn't look good (see pic):

[image]

User has to enter 3 parameters: Title, Add Image, Link

As seen in picture element shows title image id and weird link.

My question is: How can I customize what is rendered in backend editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

F`array(
         "type"      => "attach_image",
         "holder"    => "img", <!-- set in what tag to display image
         "class"     => "naujaImg", <!-- set css class
         "heading"   => __("Nuotrauka", 'element'),
         "param_name"=> "image",
         "value"     => "",
         "description" => __("Upload Image", 'element')
      )`